# Get objects from a has_many association through a self_join association in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models, `product` and `variation`. The product model has a `has_many` relationship with the variation model.  I also have a `match` model that has a self join relationship with the product model.

What I am trying to do is get an object from the variation model that has a relationship with a matched product.

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :variations, -> { order(:order) }, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :matches
  has_many :matched_products, through: :matches
  ...
end
```

**variation.rb**

```
class Variation < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  VARIATION_ORDER = %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
  validates :product_id, presence: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :products
  belongs_to :product
  ...
end
```

**match.rb**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :matched_product, class_name: 'Product'
end
```

**products/show.html.erb**
*This gives me the name object of the matched product, but I would also like to get the name of the variation associated to the matched product*

```
...
<% @product.matches.each do |c| %>
    <li><%= link_to "#{c.matched_product.name}", product_path(c.matched_product) %></li>
<% end %>
...
```

Comment: A `product` has many `variations`, what `variation` did you want to get the name? All?

Comment: @fongfan999 yes, client wants to show name of associated product and the name and images of the associated variations.

Comment: Could you show me the model `Image`?

Comment: There is no model for the image, it’s part of the variation model. The variation model has :name, :image, :body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the names of variation's images, you can do like this:

```
c.matched_product.variations.pluck(:image).join(', ')
```

---

Don't forget to use `includes(:variations)` to avoid **N+1 queries**, ie: `@product.matches.includes(:variations)`